# ADB installed apk not showing or launchable

Tags: android, installation, adb

I've installed 5 APKs using the abd install command. Three of the packages install and function as expected but the other 2 (including Brave browser) don't. If I try to access the 2 apps in question via swiping up from the bottom of the screen to reveal the app list (app drawer) but they are not shown. If I go to 'setting > apps' they are viewable but cant be opened. The output of `adb dumpsys package packages` show that the the apps are installed. Some forums suggest that this may occur if there are more than on account on the device but this isnt the case for me.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can get the apps to work as normal.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest dragging the APKs to Android Studio and check the manifest yourself to see if launcher activity exists.

Comment: Where did you got the Brave browser APK file(s) from? Are you sure they are genuine and complete (apps can be delivered in split APK format where the app is divided into multiple APK files).

Comment: Hi. I used https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/ to get the apks from google play.

Comment: That downloader site does not seem to be maintained very well. Just downloaded the Amazon app and got a version that is ~16 months old. Other sites like apkmirror or apkpure work better IMHO. Also Brave can be downloaded directly: https://brave.com/download/